# Prove that $f(x)=x^4+8x^3+x^2+2x+5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Prove that $f(x)=x^4+8x^3+x^2+2x+5$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

I've tried many methods:

Eiseinstein's criterion doesn't apply here. I've tried to project the polynomial over $\mathbb Z_2=\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}\}$, getting $f(x)=x^4+x^2+1$, but it is reducible: $f(x)=(x^2+x+1)^2$. Over $\mathbb Z_3$ the polynomial is also reducible: $f(x)=x^4+2x^3+x^2+2x+2$ has $2$ as a root. Over $\mathbb Z_5$ it is evidently reducible. Please, give me an idea!

Comment: Do you know the rational root test?

Comment: You could check all of the factorizations in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Hello! Rational root test can be endless and factorization in $\mathbb R$ imply to search for a root: it can be problematic!

Comment: You can use the rational root test (or factoring over $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$, as in Jyrki's answer) to exclude linear factors and reduce the question to confirming that there are no quadratic factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the pieces that you have together!

Modulo $2$ you have, indeed, $f(x)=(x^2+x+1)^2$. This doesn't tell us that $f$ is irreducible, but it does tell us that the only possible factorization (over $\Bbb{Z}$) is into a product of two quadratic factors - both congruent to $x^2+x+1$ modulo two.

Modulo $3$ we can use the root you found and factor
$$
f(x)=(x+1)(x^3+x^2+2).
$$
Here the latter factor $p(x)$ is seen to be irreducible. It is cubic, so it suffices to check the absence of roots in $\Bbb{Z}_3$, which is easy. We also observe that its reciprocal is 
$$
\tilde{p}(x):=x^3p(\frac1x)=-(x^3-x-1).
$$
This is of the "standard" irreducible type $x^p-x-a,a\neq0,$ over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ (search the site if you haven't seen that result yet).

Whichever way you conclude irreducibility of $p(x)$ doesn't matter. Modulo three information tells us that the only way $f$ can factor (again over $\Bbb{Z}$) is into a product of a linear and a cubic factor.

But, of course, the modulo two and modulo three bits of information are incompatible in any way other than $f$ being irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ and hence also in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: Thanks, Jyrki. Excelent explanation!